# Prevent my hosting server from adding a JavaScript snippet to my page?

Tags: htaccess, server

My host adds JavaScript in particular cases. I want to prevent that. Maybe through .htaccess?

The added code is the following
[image]

So, even preventing their PHP from executing would be useful.

Comment: Htaccess will not solve your problem. You will have to talk to your host and see if they will remove it. It may be a feature that they provide that you may want to keep. Call them ad ask about the code.

Comment: I bet this is part of their TOS and you are required to have it. Probably because the hosting is free or very cheap. In these cases you get what you pay for.

Comment: @closetnoc: "you may want to keep" - it looks like it displays an advertising banner/popup, so maybe not.

Comment: @w3d I did not look deep into what the code does. I saw count.php and thought it might be a performance analysis bug. I hate these crazy-[mule] hosts that are just plain sleazy. But then again, I keep saying "You get what you pay for." Just cough-up the 7.99 already and be done with all the bull. This is why I got out of the hosting game a decade ago.

Comment: Yeah but the host is not suppossed to add any banners.. in fact they don't, except as seen by google bot, which creeps me out because google indexing is by far a huge thing in my work. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I saw a post about this on SO

[Webhoster inserts a javascript which brokes my code how to remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268868/webhoster-inserts-a-javascript-which-brokes-my-code-how-to-remove-it)

The chosen answer states:

> They have a link in their cPanel where you can disable the analytics
>   code.
>
> http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php
>
> Beware - by doing this you violate their policy and they will
>   eventually drop you from their service and you will lose all your
>   data.

Though that was back in 2010. They may have removed this option - it would be best to just get into contact with them & see if it is possible to remove it - or if it is a violation of their Ts&Cs.

Comment: Yeah, that actually works but not for google bots (they still see the page with the banner).

Thanks anyways!

Comment: @GonzaloHLl: Now that sounds like _cloaking_, which is against Google's T&C's!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it by turning off any PHP code after my coding in html... so that the server doesn't add any of it by itself

Comment: "turning off any PHP code after..." - is this a configuration option that your host provides?

Comment: I just did this at the bottom of my site <?php exit; ?>